# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 - Even with 'InnoDB' and unsigned

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to create a foreign key on the `country_id` field from `domains` table to the `id` field of `countries`. But when I do the migration: `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Error message:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `domains` add constraint `domains_country_id_foreign` foreign key (`country_id`) references `countries` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Here is the `domains` migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('domains', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('display_name');
        $table->string('extension');
        $table->string('google_analytics')->nullable();
        $table->string('google_webmastertool')->nullable();
        $table->string('google_maps')->nullable();
        $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('actif')->default(true);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });

    Schema::table('domains', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

And here is the `countries` migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('alpha2', 2);
        $table->string('alpha3', 3);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}
```

As you can see the `country_id` field is unsigned and the table engine is InnoDB. I have already done other migrations with foreign key and they work fine, but this one, doesn't work :|

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing the `countries` migration is being run before the `domains` one. Also, is there a reason why you have the foreign key definition on the `table` closure instead of the `create` one?

Comment: I used the answer of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854693/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-laravel. For `table` instead of `create`, but before I set the foreign key in the `create` method. Same error :/

Comment: But does the `countries` migration run before the `domains` one?

Comment: I don't know, but I think it is that, because it is the only way to have this error... Do you know where or how I can manage this?

Comment: Have a look in your `database/migrations` directory and see the migration files order there, and that will tell you in which order they will be executed. If the order is indeed reversed, then just rename the timestamps at the beginning of the migration filenames so they match the order you want.

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan for your help, it was that... I changed the timestamp of `countries` earlier than `domains` table and it's work! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from @Bogdan.

**Change the order of the migration with the timestamp of the migration file.**
You need to have the file with foreign key have a **highter timestamp** than the timestamp of the migration file where the primary key is located.